# Add domain to generate SSL certificate that is not mentioned in nginx conf for certbot

Tags: nginx, ssl, lets-encrypt, certbot

I generated my SSL certificate for (example) a.com (it was automatically detected in my nginx config). Now, I have another domain b.com pointing to the same ipaddress as a.com but not mentioned in my nginx conf.

How can I generate an SSL certificate for both of these domains using cerbot? If I run certbot it only lets me choose a.com because it is mentioned in my nginx conf but not b.com because its not mentioned.

Thank you.

Comment: Read the [docs](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#certbot-commands) carefully. Generally it is `certbot certonly --webroot -w <server_root> -d a.com -d b.com`

Comment: @Ivan Shatsky is it possible to do this now, even though I have already generated a certificate for a.com?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I think it should be ok since you are requesting a different certificate.